# Given a point (x,y,z) and an angle/bearing distance calculate the end point (x,y,z)

Tags: 3d

I'm not very mathematical but I'm working on a 3d program and for this part I simply want to draw a line.

I know the starting vector (x,y,z), the length r of the line and the bearing/angle. I want to calculate the endpoint so I can draw the line.

I had a look around and I'm using the following. Let θ be the angle in radians, and let d be the distance. Then the other endpoint is (x′,y′,z′), where:

X=3500
Y=0
Z=2000

r=150000
angle= 64.322

What is my End Point (x',y',z')

Comment: When you say angle, I'm assuming you mean on the X-Y plane? Otherwise, you either need to know the plane that the angle exists in, or a second angle.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "bearing" is an angle measured in the $xy$-plane, with $\text{bearing} = 0$ on the $x$-axis, we have:
$$
x' = x + r*\cos(\theta) \\
y' = y + r*\sin(\theta) \\
z' = z
$$
If your angle is in degrees, remember to convert it to radians before you pass it to the sine and cosine functions.

**Alternative**

It actually looks like your angle $\theta$ is measured in the $xz$-plane. So, the relevant formulae are:
$$
x' = x - r*\cos(\theta) \\
y' = y   \quad \text{(roughly)} \\
z' = z + r*\sin(\theta)
$$
Since the line is 3D, you need **two** angles to determine its direction. You only gave us one ($\theta$) so that's why the formula for $y$ doesn't give the right answer. Actually, the results for $x$ and $z$ are not 100% accurate, either. With only one angle, this is the best possible.

Comment: thanx Mr bubba for your answer. but from this type the end points are not correct

Comment: ur procedure is not correct any other procedure

Comment: His procedure is correct unless there is any additional information in the question. Please clarify your question.

Comment: actually for this procedure my end points are not comming (corrected end points are -61495,755,137184)

Comment: In your example, $z$ and $z'$ are different, so the line must not be horizontal (parallel to the $xy$ plane). So, your angle $\theta$ is not as I assumed. You need to explain what your $\theta$ means.

Comment: Angle Theta is 64.322 degs

Comment: > Angle Theta is 64.322 degs -- Yes, you said that already. The question is about its *meaning*, not its value. Where is it measured from? In what direction? Where is $\theta = 0$?